# How do I set the active menu item dynamically for a view?

Tags: views, 6, navigation

How do I change the active menu item when showing a view? [How do I dynamically set the active menu item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087141/drupal-how-to-set-active-menu-item-dynamically/3090538#3090538) shows how to do for nodes (using `hook_nodeapi()`), but how can I achieve the same for a view?

I tried `hook_views_pre_view()`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: If a view is associated with a menu item, isn't that menu item active when the view is being shown?

Comment: The final goal for me is to activate the last menu item (referrer) again, so that the menue stays the same depending from where you came. Thats what I ment with dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and set condition to be your view and reaction to be menu link.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to use the [Menu position module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position), it lets you make rules for when and what menu item is selected. Also [Menu trails](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) is something you could check out.